# matplotlib: draw special symbol when a value appears

Tags: python, graph, matplotlib, plot

Using `matplotlib` I would like to plot a list of delays such that:

- on the **X-axis** I have the position of the delay in the list
- on the **Y-axis** I have the delay itself

Now, in my list there is a **special value** 'L' which I want to draw as a **red cross** on the X-axis whenever it occurs.

How can I do this last thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of different ways to do this.

To start with, let's make your data a numpy array so that we can use boolean indexing.  This allows easier isolation of the "flagged" `"L"` values from the data values.

Ideally, you'd convert things to a masked array with the "L" values masked (and floats everywhere, instead of mixed data types).  For the sake of simplicity, though, let's just use an object array here so that you can mix strings and floats.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

delays = np.array([0.5, 2.3, 'L', 0.9, 'L', 2], dtype=object)
x = np.arange(delays.size)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x[delays != 'L'], delays[delays != 'L'], 'bo')

# Expand axis limits by 0.5 in all directions for easier viewing
limits = np.array(ax.axis())
ax.axis(limits + [-0.5, 0.5, -0.5, 0.5])

flag_positions = x[delays == 'L']
ax.plot(flag_positions, np.zeros_like(flag_positions), 'rx', 
        clip_on=False, mew=2)

plt.show()
```

[image]

However, the red x's are at a fixed y-position, and if we pan or zoom, they'll move off the x-axis.

You can get around this by using a custom transform.  In this case, we want the x-coordinates to use the "normal" data coordinates (`ax.transData`) and the y-coordinates to use the axes coordinate system (e.g. 0-1 where 0 is the bottom and  1 is the top: `ax.transAxes`).  To do this, we'll use a `BlendedGenericTransform`, which uses two different transforms: one for the x-coordinates and another for the y-coordinates.

So, if you want the red `x`'s to always be on the x-axis regardless of how the plot is panned or zoomed, then you might do something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.transforms import BlendedGenericTransform

delays = np.array([0.5, 2.3, 'L', 0.9, 'L', 2], dtype=object)
x = np.arange(delays.size)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x[delays != 'L'], delays[delays != 'L'], 'bo')

flags = x[delays == 'L']
ax.plot(flags, np.zeros_like(flags), 'rx', clip_on=False, mew=2,
        transform=BlendedGenericTransform(ax.transData, ax.transAxes))

# Expand axis limits by 0.5 in all directions for easier viewing
limits = np.array(ax.axis())
ax.axis(limits + [-0.5, 0.5, -0.5, 0.5])

plt.show()
```

[image]

We can make things a bit cleaner by using masked arrays (also have a look at `pandas`). Using masked arrays (or, again, `pandas`) is a better option for indicating missing data than using an object array with mixed string and float values.  As an example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.transforms import BlendedGenericTransform

delays = [0.5, 2.3, 'L', 0.9, 'L', 2]
delays = [item if item != 'L' else np.nan for item in delays]
delays = np.ma.masked_invalid(delays)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(delays, 'bo')

flags = delays.mask.nonzero()
ax.plot(flags, np.zeros_like(flags), 'rx', clip_on=False, mew=2,
        transform=BlendedGenericTransform(ax.transData, ax.transAxes))

# Expand axis limits by 0.5 in all directions for easier viewing
limits = np.array(ax.axis())
ax.axis(limits + [-0.5, 0.5, -0.5, 0.5])

plt.show()
```